# How to interpret SHAP summary plot when some features represent are all negative or positive values?

Tags: python, random-forest, shapley-value

I've been working on a random forest model to estimate the probability of soil erosion and used SHAP to understand the feature contributions. Typically, I expect to see a mix of positive and negative SHAP values for each feature indicating their respective push on the model's output. However, when I made a SHAP summary plot for my model, the results seem atypical. For example, the 'LAI_ann (annual leaf area index)' feature exclusively shows negative SHAP values. Similarly, 'Slp' (slope) and 'Silt content' features are all positive. This is different from general summary plots I'm used to seeing.

Has anyone experienced similar situations or is there a known reason for such a pattern? If this result is plausible, I'd appreciate insights into how to interpret these kinds of unidirectional SHAP values in the context of soil erosion prediction.

[image]